# How to fix HTML being output before PHP that is coded before it?

Tags: php, html, html-table, output

I have this code:

```
<table><tr><th>Select a Ramp: </th></tr>

<?php 

global $dbc;
$rampq="SELECT item_id, item_name FROM items WHERE category_id = '1'";
$rampr = @mysqli_query($dbc, $rampq) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));            
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rampr)){
     echo '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="rampGroup" 
           value="' . $row['item_id'] . '"';
        if(isset($_POST['rampGroup']) && $_POST['rampGroup']==$row['item_id']){
            echo 'checked="checked"';}echo'>' . $row['item_name'] . '</tr>';  }

            echo '<tr><input type="radio" name="rampGroup" value="0"';if(isset($_POST['rampGroup']) && $_POST['rampGroup']==0){echo 'checked="checked"';} 
            echo'>No Ramp</tr></table>';
?>
```

When this code is outputted on a browser it looks like:

o No Ramp
Select a Ramp:
o Hydraulic Single Gate
o Hydraulic Double Fold Gate

The "no ramp" is supposed to be printed last, but it jumps above the items returned from the query.  Is there any way to get this to output correctly?

Comment: You can press ctrl+u to debug

Comment: Put it in a td then your table code is invalid

Answer (score 1):

Your html is invalid. The `noramp` item is not contained within a `<td>` or `<th>`, so the browser is moving it to the "top" of the table.

```
        echo '<tr><input type="radio" name="rampGroup" value="0"';
                  ^----missing <td> here
        echo'>No Ramp</tr></table>';
                     ^---missing </td> here
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way

```
global $dbc;
$rampq="SELECT item_id, item_name FROM items WHERE category_id = '1'";
$rampr = @mysqli_query($dbc, $rampq) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));            
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rampr)){
   if(isset($_POST['rampGroup']) && $_POST['rampGroup']==$row['item_id']){
        $checked= 'checked="checked"';}
   if(isset($_POST['rampGroup']) && $_POST['rampGroup']==0)
       {$checked= 'checked="checked"';}
   echo '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="rampGroup" value="' . $row['item_id'] . '"'.$checked.'>'. $row['item_name'].'<td></tr>';
   echo '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="rampGroup" value="0"'.$checked.'No Ramp></td></tr>'; 
        echo'></tr></table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a couple things;

First, indentation: I will really help you to have a clear indentation, especially for while and ifs in this case.

Second, verifying tags: Make sure you build the opening tag and the closing tag for your element; (ie; in your while, put `echo "<tr>";` as first line and `echo "</tr>";` as last line`)
It is better to have more lines of codes, and being able to identify the tags easily.
(at least before refactoring when everything works fine)

Third, validating your html: You can check it either with the "view source code" button or with the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/). Both will help you finding error in your html and find out why it isn’t showing properly.

With all that in mind, I would refartor your code like this:

```
<table>
<tr><th>Select a Ramp: </th></tr>

<?php 
global $dbc;
$rampq="SELECT item_id, item_name FROM items WHERE category_id = '1'";
$rampr = @mysqli_query($dbc, $rampq) or die(mysqli_error($dbc)); 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rampr)){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td><input type="radio" name="rampGroup" value="' . $row['item_id'] . '"';
    if(isset($_POST['rampGroup']) && $_POST['rampGroup']==$row['item_id']){
        echo ' checked="checked"';
    }
    echo'>' . $row['item_name'] . '</td>';  
    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '<tr>';
echo '<td><input type="radio" name="rampGroup" value="0"';
if(isset($_POST['rampGroup']) && $_POST['rampGroup']==0) {
    echo 'checked="checked"';
}
echo'>No Ramp</td>';
echo '</tr>';
?> 

</table>
```